# Динамическое добавление addItem

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qcombobox

На вход я получаю некоторый список, который потом должен отобразиться в пользовательском интерфейсе.

Создаю объект класса `QComboBox`, ума не приложу каким образом сделать то, что мне нужно. Пока что это выглядит так:

```
combo = QComboBox
gh = len(sheets)
i = 0
while i < gh:
    combo.addItem(sheets[i])
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `QComboBox.addItems(texts)`
>   Добавляет каждую строку в указанные тексты в поле со списком. Каждый элемент >добавляется к списку существующих элементов по очереди.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        sheets = [str(i) for i in range(1, 10)]   # Какой-то список строк !
        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()

        combo.addItems(sheets)                    # <-----         

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
import string
import random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        sheets = [random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(10)]
        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        for i in sheets:
            combo.addItem(i)
        # или list(map(combo.addItem, sheets))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```